# Convert Lowercase Letters to Uppercase in C Language

Tags: c

I'm working on a simple piece of program to incorporate into a larger program. I'm following what my professor has already taught.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char letter;
printf("Please Enter a Lower Case Letter:");
scanf("%s", letter);

if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
  letter = letter - 'a' + 'A';
printf("%s", letter);
return 0;
}
```

The initial 'Please Enter a Lowercase Letter:' appears but after inputting a letter the return is (null). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: read up on format specifiers and %s vs %c

Comment: Er, why not use [toupper()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)? -- Also, your compiler isn't complaining loudly about your code? If not, increase warning levels (Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` with gcc and clang).

Comment: Also note well that `scanf()` expects you to pass *pointers* to the locations in which to store converted values.  You're passing a `char` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`. Links to C reference for [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) and [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char letter;
printf("Please Enter a Lower Case Letter:");
letter = getchar();

if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
  letter = letter - 'a' + 'A';
printf("%c", letter);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", letter);` will read a string and copy it to the memory `letter` points to so pass the pointer of `letter` instead (`scanf("%s", &letter);`).
Also use `%c` instead of `%s` if you only need one character otherwise `scanf` can write some unwanted bytes to adjacent memory.
Likewise for the last `printf` line.